# Insert 2 tables dynamically in word document using OpenXML

Tags: ms-word, openxml

I have a requirement to insert 2 tables in word document. I am using the OpenXML API for it. When I try inserting the second table it gives me an error - `Cannot insert the OpenXmlElement “newChild” because it is part of a tree`.

The following is my code:

```
if (fieldname.Trim().Equals("Table"))
{
    if (!checkCount)
    {
         var tabRun = new Run(table);
         var anc = field.Ancestors<Paragraph>().FirstOrDefault();
         anc.RemoveAllChildren();
         anc.Append(tabRun);
     }
     else
     {
         var tabRun = table;
         var anc = field.Ancestors<Paragraph>().FirstOrDefault();
         anc.RemoveAllChildren();
         anc.Append(tabRun);
     }
}
```

Here the flag `checkCount` would be true when the code would execute for the second time. `fieldname` refers to the mergefield that will be replaced by the table.

I am unable to figure out the cause of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211754/open-office-xml-sdk-exception-cannot-insert-the-openxmlelement-newchild-becau) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320537/cannot-insert-the-openxmlelement-newchild-because-it-is-part-of-a-tree/16565213#16565213), you need to clone the node to insert in advance to handle the issue. The error occurs because you're trying to add a node that's not freshly created, but part of a tree already.

Comment: Are you creating and assigning the `table` variable on each iteration of your loop? If not, your else-sentence (the part of the code that fails) has to create a new `table` node that wasn't added to the document earlier.